# Programmatic circle diagram approach/technology

Tags: illustrator-scripting, html

I'd like to make something like this programatically.

http://www.feelingswheel.com/

> [image]

Does anyone have a suggestion? Could you approach this programmatically with Illustrator, Inkscape, HTML5, or Three.JS?

Comment: Hi and welcome to GDSE! Do you have any programming experience? Hard to know where to start when you don't show us what you have tried. Does it have to be programmatical? Only makes sense if you are going to make a lot of different wheels. If you're just making one it would be faster to just construct it manually.

Comment: Yes you can do this with all the technologies you asked. But seems to me you need to do the choice.

Comment: Graphics created in Illustrator or Inkscape can be saved as SVG (scalable vector graphics), which is a kind of XML, a markup language.  You can edit that code in a text editor, in fact you can even manually code an entire SVG without any graphics software if you feel so inclined.

Answer (score 1):

“Sunburst chart” is one common name of this type. It's been implemented in, i.a., JavaScript. If you don't want to install the one or other programming environment, you can peruse one of the existing templates on *[Observable](https://observablehq.com/search?query=sunburst%20chart&onlyOwner=false)*, a community and infrastructure for online JavaScript notebooks. See, e.g., this [live generator](https://observablehq.com/@mbostock/sunburst-o-matic). Other templates for live editing on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/search/pens?q=sunburst) (e.g. [this](https://highcharts.com/samples/highcharts/demo/sunburst?codepen)), [etc.](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=sunburst%20chart%20online%20editor).

Answer (score 0):

You should use Scalable Vector Graphics (SVG) for this type of graphic. You can code SVG directrly in a text editor or use some vector graphics software. If you want to control the colors, borders etc. you have to make them variables. You can also assign id and class to different elements within the SVG and control them with CSS ... it's just the way to go.